# StreamingContext is empty in Windows Store SDK, how can deserialization context be passed using json.net?

Tags: json.net, windows-store-apps

In Json.Net, I'm setting the Context (type StreamingContext) object on JsonSerializerSettings to pass down information that objects use during deserialization in an [OnDeserialized] method. I do this by creating a new StreamingContext object and setting the additional object parameter. This all works perfectly in non-windows store builds:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString, DeserializationContext context = null)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            // Win store builds fail on this line:
            Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Other, context),
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString, settings);
```

In the Windows Store SDK, the [StreamingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.aspx) object exists but is empty (both Context and State don't exist, and it has no non-default constructor). It seems that this object is now completely useless, as it is now simply an empty struct!

Does anyone know a way to get around this new limitation and pass down context like in non-windows store builds?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the json.net source. I changed the Context object on JsonSerializer to be of type object instead of StreamingContext and bubbling those changes through the rest of the source. This allowed me to avoid the blank StreamingContext structure in .NET for Windows Store. Not convinced this is the best solution, but it's certainly working for me now.